Unable to retrieve a value of a CheckBox when reading a csv file
I have the following code which saves the isChecked value to a csv file. When I open and read the file back I can never access the False value, it always shows the CheckBox as clicked (True)
`class Settings(QDialog, Ui_d_Settings):
def init(self):
super().init()
self.setupUi(self)
    self.open_settings()

    self.cb_HeightMapsEnable.stateChanged.connect(self.get_heightmap_enable)


def open_settings(self):
    filename = r'VRPsS10.ini'
    path_names = ['Name', 'Setting']

    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(f, path_names)
        for line in csv_reader:

            if line['Name'] == 'Enable':
                self.cb_HeightMapsEnable.setChecked(bool(line['Setting']))

def get_heightmap_enable(self):
    self.save_setting()

def save_setting(self):
    filename = r'VRPsS10.ini'
    path_names = ['Name', 'Setting']

    paths = [
        {'Name': 'Enable', 'Setting': self.cb_HeightMapsEnable.isChecked()},
        {'Name': 'heightmaps Path', 'Setting': self.le_HeightMapsPath.text()}]

    with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=path_names)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(paths)`

I have tried to work through many solutions but none have worked. What I'm trying to achieve is when I saved the value as False and I open it again it still reflects the corect value. False to False and True to True

bool(some_string) will not convert it, it just checks whether the string is empty or not: bool('False') will still result as True. Use string comparison instead: setChecked(line['Setting'] == 'True'). Even better, in case you're using case insensitive values: line['Setting'].lower() == 'true'.

Thanks musicamante, this did the trick. Appreciate your help
